# Monte Carlo simulation of 8 coin flips

Tags: r, for-loop, simulation, montecarlo, purrr

I am trying to solve the following problem with Monte Carlo simulation

> Let's say that head = 1 and tails = 0 and I flip 8 coins. What is the probability that all are tails?

What I have so far is the following

```
sum(sample(c(0,1),8,replace=T))
```

This counts the number of heads in a sample of 8. I would like to run this `1e6` times and count the number of times 0 shows up, divided by `1e6`. What are some various ways to accomplish this in R?

Comment: `?replicate` ....

Comment: Thanks, `replicate` did it `sum(replicate(1e6,sum(sample(c(0,1),8,replace=T))==0))/1e6` = `.004`

Comment: (possibly after a little while) you can post an answer to your own question

Comment: do you really want "various ways"?  `for` loop, `plyr::raply()`, `purrr::rerun()`, ...

Comment: I would definitely like to see a `purrr` implementation. Of all of the `tidyverse` `purrr` is this most difficult for me to understand. I don't need to see `for` loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's most of a `purrr` solution

```
set.seed(101)
n <- 1e5
xx <- rerun(n,sample(0:1,8,replace=TRUE)) %>%  map_dbl(sum) 
mean(xx==0)
```

You can do the last step functionally via

```
... %>% tibble %>% summarise(prob=mean(.==0))
```

(`.` is the single unnamed variable in the tibble) but that feels kind of cheesy